# How to find out what parameters a dynamic link can take?

Tags: html, hyperlink, dynamic-links

For links like the one below, where I can add multiple parameters with the "&" operator, is there a way to find out all possible arguments for a link like this?

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=EMAIL@EMAIL.COM

I'm looking for something similar to dir(object) in Python

I've tried searching for this, but I'm beginning to think I'm using the wrong keywords as I'm not finding much of use.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard way to discover this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I started to suspect the same.